# partial apply for closure #1

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarView: View {
    @State private var monthName: String
    @State private var dayNumber: Int
    
    init(withMonth month: Int, andDay day: Int) {
        self.dayNumber = day
        let itLocale = Locale(identifier: "it_IT")
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = itLocale
        self.monthName = formatter.shortMonthSymbols[month - 1].uppercased()
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 44.5, height: 47)
                .cornerRadius(8.0)
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.accentColor)
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 20)
                    Text(self.monthName)
                        .font(.caption)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
                
                ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 44, height: 26)
                        
                    Text(String(format: "%02d", self.dayNumber))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)   
                }
            }
            .cornerRadius(8.0)
        }
    }
}

struct CalendarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CalendarView(withMonth: 4, andDay: 9)
    }
}
```

This is the crash log:

```
6  SwiftUI                        0x18a0ea260 partial apply for closure #1 in ViewBodyAccessor.updateBody(of:changed:) + 40
7  SwiftUI                        0x18a490c7c closure #1 in BodyAccessor.setBody(_:) + 52
8  SwiftUI                        0x18a0e222c ViewBodyAccessor.updateBody(of:changed:) + 1520
9  SwiftUI                        0x18a491158 DynamicBody.updateValue() + 492
10 SwiftUI                        0x18a10ab34 partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 32
```

`CalendarView` is a small view drawing an icon like macOS Calendar icon. I call this view in a loop giving month number and day number as parameters to create a list of calendar icons containing day number and first 3 letters of month name.

Day and month numbers come from a working network request that always returns same list (no empty values)

So far so good, when in debug mode it works flawlessly: I tested (debug) it on real iPad, iPhone and simulators with no issues, but it always fails giving a crash in release builds (TestFlight).
I don't know why or where to start looking to fix it...

**edit**:
Crash log above is only last part of entire log that can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/DjXSMDY2)

Comment: Are you sure this is the entire crash log? It seems like you posted just a small part of the stack trace. Isn't there any error message?

Comment: @Rengers yes it is only a small part. I edited my question adding link to full log

Comment: Your crash is at this line: `2  Balubbah              0x10039be54 (Missing)`. That's in your app, and you need to symbolicate the logs to find out where. The piece of the crash you listed is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @RobNapier I uploaded dSym to Crashlytics for this crash and this is the only log I have right now...maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Also, I would highly recommend running this in release mode under Xcode. You may find the problem there. You don't need to use TestFlight just to build in release mode.

Comment: @RobNapier yes you're right, I'm using testflight because right now I don't have any device here to test it in release

Comment: You can run release on simulators, too.

Comment: (Probably unrelated, but I don't think there's any reason to use `@State` on your properties here. They're never mutated, so they can just be normal properties.)

Comment: There's no evidence that the crash is in this view. I would expect it is elsewhere. In the part that you describe as "I call this view in a loop" for example (it's not clear what you mean by "call this view" or what kind of loop you mean). Or it could be somewhere else. This crash could be from modifying things on a non-main thread from the network callback, for example. You'll need a symbolicated crash log to be sure.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for suggestions (for `State` and running release on simulator), I try in few minutes

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, this could be driven by something on the network callback, but..why only in release mode and never in debug? This is the main problem I cannot understand...

Comment: This is a memory management issue (note that crash in swift_retain). That is exactly the kind of bug you'd see show up differently under different optimization settings. In release mode, you expect objects to be destroyed faster than in debug mode, so if you create dangling pointers, they're more likely to create actual crashes in release mode. If you run your code under the thread sanitizer and the address sanitizer, it may also show you where you're going wrong.

Comment: Ok, I tried to run code under the thread sanitizer and address sanitizer with no luck (no useful info gathered), then I tried to remove `State` property wrapper as @RobNapier suggested and it worked. I tested it in debug and release and no more crash so..thanks Rob!